# Bootstrap input-group-addon Not Vertically Aligned

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, textfield

I'm using the following markup with Bootstrap:

```
<div class="row">

    <label class="col-md-4">Date of Completion of Checklist</label>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker">
            <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I have some of my own CSS in a separate file, including:

```
.form-control {
    border-color: #000;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #009966;
}

label {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

.input-group-addon {
    background: #fff;
    border-color: #000;
}
```

However, even when I remove my whole custom stylesheet, I am still presented with this vertical alignment issue you can see below:

[image]

It looks like it's 1 pixel off what it should be. I've tried setting the positioning to `relative` and set `bottom: 1px` however it doesn't appear to budge.

If I remove the `vertical-align` property it completely messes up the look of it.

Does anyone have an idea what could be causing the problem?

Comment: if you inspect it do you see anything specifically that is causing the offset? make sure you inspect the div's inside too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.glyphicon {
    top: 1px;
}
```

change this to `top:0px;` or add `style="top:0px;"` top your span

Answer (score 1):

Changing your html to this fixes it:

```
<div class="row">

    <label class="col-md-4">Date of Completion of Checklist</label>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

i have moved the `glyphicon glyphicon-calendar` class to an `<i>` inside your `span`, which now aligns all correctly.

Comment: It would be useful to explain what's different here... (the nesting of the `<i>` tag *inside* the `<span>` tag)

Comment: @Lee: Bootstrap's `glyphicon` class has `top: 1px;` on default, which will cause an offset, unless you nest the icon in its own element within the outer `input-group-addon`.

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this input-group-addon and place span above input

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups