# Glyphicons inside input-group-addon not aligned vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The glyphicons inside of the input-group-addon are not aligned vertically, they seems to be hanging lower by several px.

I looked at the posts on this page:

[Bootstrap input-group-addon Not Vertically Aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938365/bootstrap-input-group-addon-not-vertically-aligned)
but none of them soved my problem.

here's my code:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" style='font-size: 15px;' id="email_input" class="input form-control big"
        value="" name="email_input" data-required_mark="required" data-field_type="email"
        data-original_id="email" placeholder="Email address">
    <span class="input-group-addon">        
        <i id="email_error_X" class="error_glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"
            style="display: inline-block;">
        </i>
    </span>
</div>
```

and here's some of my css:

```
.error_glyphicon {
    display: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: red;
    /* background-color: yellow; */
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
}
```

yes, the `display: none` and `display: inline-block` are contradictory, but the latter overrides the former, as I want it.
And of course I'm not getting any error messages or anything.
here's a snippet of the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kupg.png)
as you can see the symbol is not aligned.

Comment: Could you provide a snippet so we could help you better?

Comment: I tried adding a picture, but the link above goes to a nonexistent page.

Comment: I would say to get that small part of your code in some website that can run it, like codepen or plunker... so we can see what your problem is and try and give you a better solution.

Comment: Actually, sorry for your time, but I solved it, some styles were conflicting in a different part. thanks for the time though..

Comment: No problem mate. Happy coding =}